# Codility - FrogRiverOne

Tags: javascript

I've googled and asked people about this question, but can't get the meaning. I know my solution is incorrect, but I hope it can help (it's on JS):

```js
let C = [1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4],
  Y = 4;

function solution(X, A) {

  var leaves = [];
  var i = 0;
  var result = -1;

  for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (typeof leaves[A[i]] == 'undefined') {
      leaves[A[i]] = i;
    }
  }

  if (leaves.length <= X) {
    return -1;
  }

  for (i = 1; i <= X; i++) {
    if (typeof leaves[i] == 'undefined') {
      return -1;
    } else {
      result = Math.max(result, leaves[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(solution(Y, C));
```

I don't need a solution to the task, I just need its clearer explanation, i.e what I have to do to solve it.

Comment: What is this code supposed to accomplish? What would be the expected result for this input? What happens instead? Your variable names are completely unhelpful.

Comment: what is *FrogRiverOne*, and what should your code do?

Comment: "I've googled and asked people about this question" what question?

Comment: i dont understand the problem, but here is the description: https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/frog_river_one/

Comment: [answer1](https://gist.github.com/divmgl/05f3bc7205a2f6c71a8f) and [answer2](https://codepen.io/alexanderyarm/pen/oLvBbB), you can get answer.

Comment: Can't provide description here, because of the restrictions. Here's the link: https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/frog_river_one/

Comment: Given an array A and an integer X, find the lowest index N so that the subsequence A[0] ... A[N] contains every number between 1 and N at least once. If no such N exists, return -1. This is the task. If you're allowed to use hash sets, all you have to do is iterate over A and add each number you encounter to the set, until the size of the set reaches X (in which case you return the current index) or you reach the end of the array (in which case you return -1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out your problem for you. Your solution is actually almost correct, but you overcomplicated the evaluation. All you have to do is initialize a counter variable to 0, and as you iterate over A in the first loop, whenever `leaves[A[i]]` is `undefined`, increment this counter. This indicates that a leaf has fallen into a position where there is no leaf yet. If after incrementing the counter is equal to X, it means all positions now have leaves on them, so just return `i`. If your loop makes it all the way to the end of `A`, it means there are uncovered positions, so return -1.

Comment: Máté Safranka, I've added a counter and modified the first loop this way: let c = 0;
    for(i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        if(typeof leaves[A[i]] == 'undefined') {
            //leaves[A[i]] = i;
            c++;
        }
    }
    if (c == X){ return c;}    Would that work?

Comment: 1. Don't comment out `leaves[A[i]] = i;`, that's how you keep track of which positions have leaves on them. 2. Move `if (c == X){ return c; }` inside the loop after `c++`, and return `i` instead of `c`. Is it clear how that works?

Comment: No, I don't know why this particular task is so hard to comprehend for me. The code below generates the wrong answer, -1 instead of 6.

Comment: function solution(X, A) {
    let leaves = [], i, c = 0;
    for(i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        if(typeof leaves[A[i]] == 'undefined'){
            leaves[A[i]] = i;
            c++;
        }
        if (c == X){ 
            return i;
            break;
        }else if(leaves.length <= X){
            return -1;
            break;
        }   
    }
}

Comment: You're still overcomplicating it. Here's what I had in mind: `function solution(X, A) {
    let leaves = [], i, c = 0;
    for(i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        if(typeof leaves[A[i]] == 'undefined') {
            leaves[A[i]] = i; c++;
            if (c == X) { return i; }
        }
    } return -1;
}`

Comment: Wow, you are right! Your solution gave 72% score (my first code estimated only 18%). Thanks a lot! It's not perfect yet, because of the correctness tests. If you are interested, please take a look: https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training5QQSWM-XTJ/

Answer (score 13):

Simple 100% solution using Set().  Being a Set can only contain unique values, you can simply iterate through array A, adding the values into a Set until the size of Set equals the integer X, at which point that array key is the solution.

```
function solution(X, A) {

    let holdValues = new Set();
    for(i=0;i<A.length;i++) {
        holdValues.add(A[i]);
        if(holdValues.size == X)return i;
    }

    return -1;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My **java** Solution (100% Correctness, 100% Performance) it has:

Time complexity => O(N)
Space complexity => O(X)

```
 public int solution(int X, int[] A) {

    int[] flags = new int[X + 1];
    int sum = 0;

    //Equivalent to all the leafs have fallen. 
    int desiredSum = (X * (X + 1)) / 2; // 1 + 2 + ....n = (n * (n + 1)) / 2

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {

        //Verify if the leaf [i] has fallen. 
        if (A[i] <= X && flags[A[i]] == 0) {
            flags[A[i]] = 1;
            sum += A[i];
        }

        //Verify if all the leafs have fallen.
        if (sum == desiredSum) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using javascript:

```js
function solution(X, A) {
    
    let set = new Set();
    
    for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        if(A[i] <= X){
            set.add(A[i]);
        }
        
        if(set.size === X){
            return i;
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is better than Set, the complexity of updating or getting count of dic is O(1).

```swift
public func solution(_ x : Int, _ array: [Int]) -> Int {
    let count = array.count
    if x > count { return -1 }
    
    var map = [Int: Bool]()
    for i in 0..<count {
        map[array[i]] = true

        if map.count == x {
            return i
        }
    }
    
    return -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
        int sec = -1;
        Set<Integer> checkList = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if(A[i] >= 1 && A[i] <= X && checkList.size() < X) {
                checkList.add(A[i]);
                if (sec < i) {
                    sec = i;
                }
            }
            if(checkList.size() == X) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(checkList.toString());
        if(checkList.size() < X) {
            sec = -1;
        }
        return sec;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would you maybe provide some explanation to your answer so that others can understand it better? Code is excellent but in the end SO is for answering questions, not just for posting solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function solution(A) {
    let count = Math.floor(A.length / 2);

    let map = new Map();

    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        map.set(A[i], map.has(A[i]) ? map.get(A[i]) + 1 : 1);

    for (const k of map.keys())
        if (map.get(k) > count)
            return A.indexOf(k);

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C#:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
...
    public static int solution(int X, int[] A)
            {
                HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>();
                for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
                {
                    numbers.Add(A[i]);
    
                    if (numbers.Count==X)
                    {
                        return i;
                    }
                  }
                  return -1;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Javascript, 100%, O(N), its a bit quicker than using sets on the performance tests. Longest part of this exercise was figuring out the question! Anyway, here's my solution:

```
function solution(X, A) {
  let newArray = new Array(X + 1);

  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (!newArray[A[i]]) {
      newArray[A[i]] = true;
      X--;

      if (!X) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution, java score 100:

```
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int response = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        set.add(A[i]);
        if (set.size() == X){
            response = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a maximum score solution in C++ for completeness:

I was searching for the optimum in performance and space but also elegance. In performance [bachiri-taoufiq-abderrahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3914166/bachiri-taoufiq-abderrahman)'s flagging solution in Java was clearly better than set/map lookup but calculating the series for `0 + 1 + 2 + ... n = n * (n + 1) / 2` is actually not necessary for solving the task. Since all position changes are steps of size 1 a regular position counter is sufficient. Also, a vector<bool> can improve space requirements because it might be implemented as bitset in C++.

```cpp
#include <vector>

int solution(int X, std::vector<int> &A) 
{
   std::vector<bool> seen(X, false);

   int position = 0;
   int time = 0;

   for (int t=0; t < static_cast<int>(A.size()); ++t)
   {
      // each element of A is within the range [1, X]
      auto const index = A[t] - 1;
      if (index < X && !seen[index])
      {
         seen[index] = true;
         if (t > time)
             time = t;
         if (++position == X)
            break;
      }
   }
   
   return position == X ? time : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain java solution

```
 class Solution {
        public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
            // write your code in Java SE 8
    
            int leaves = A.length;
            int counter=0;
            int [] path= new int [X+1];
    
            for (int t=0; t<leaves; t++){
                if(path[A[t]]!=A[t]){
                path[A[t]]=A[t];
                counter++;
                }
                if (counter==X)
                return t;
    
    
            }  
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and why it's different from the other answers given.